# Can I make a derived class inherit a derived member from its base class in Java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have code that looks like this:

```
public class A
{
    public void doStuff()
    {
        System.out.print("Stuff successfully done");
    }
}

public class B extends A
{
    public void doStuff()
    {
        System.out.print("Stuff successfully done, but in a different way");
    }

    public void doMoreStuff()
    {

        System.out.print("More advanced stuff successully done");
    }
}

public class AWrapper
{
    public A member;

    public AWrapper(A member)
    {
        this.member = member;
    }

    public void doStuffWithMember()
    {
        a.doStuff();
    }
}

public class BWrapper extends AWrapper
{
    public B member;

    public BWrapper(B member)
    {
        super(member);         //Pointer to member stored in two places:
        this.member = member;  //Not great if one changes, but the other does not

    }

    public void doStuffWithMember()
    {
        member.doMoreStuff();
    }
}
```

However, there is a problem with this code. I'm storing a reference to the member in two places, but if one changes and the other does not, there could be trouble. I know that in Java, an inherited method can narrow down its return type (and perhaps arguments, but I'm not certain) to a derived class. Is the same true of fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this better with generics.

```
public class AWrapper<T extends A>
{
    public T member;
    public AWrapper(T member)
    {
        this.member = member;
    }

    public void doStuffWithMember()
    {
        a.doStuff();
    }
}    

public class BWrapper extends Wrapper<B>
{
    public BWrapper(B member)
    {
        super(member);
    }

    public void doStuffWithMember()
    {
        member.doMoreStuff();
    }
}
```

The fact that the subclass wrapper specifies the type of B allows you to access B's functions in the BWrapper, without storing an additional reference.

Comment: Not necessarily.  You can genericize the wrapper as many layers deep as you want, but if you're doing this kind of coding you're probably modeling the domain wrong.

Comment: Ah sorry, I confused with my past expereince where I didn't want to genericize second level class for readability issues.  Yes, one is willing to make `BWrapper` generic it will work fine.

Comment: What does this syntax mean? `public <T> class`? I've only ever seem type parameters _after_ identifiers

Comment: @Eric I was confusing the syntax for static method declarations of generic types with the class declaration format.  Edited to fix.

Comment: Yeah, but I've still seen that syntax elsewhere on SO. Is it ever appropriate, or is it just a common mistake?

Answer (score 0):

In your class `BWrapper` you have to remove the line `public B member;`. And in the method `doMoreStuffWithMember()` replace the line with:

```
((B) member).doMoreStuff();
```

Comment: @Jherico: But in this case you are sure it is an instance of `B`.

Comment: You cannot be sure as written here, because `AWrapper.member` is `public` and could be set to a non-`B` instance. You would not even be safe if the attribute was `protected`, because some subclass of `BWrapper` could set the attribute.